# Undefined element getting JSON from URL

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm using google maps API to get elevation value by LAT and LON but I'm getting always undefined objects.

My script is this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
        function findAltitude() {
            var lat  = document.getElementById('lat').value;
            var lon  = document.getElementById('lon').value;

            var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=11,11&key=<API_KEY>";

            var json, data;

            $.ajax({
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: url,
                  data: data,
                  success: function(data) {
                       alert(data.results.elevation);
                    }
                });
        }

  </script>
```

and my JSON is this:

```
{"results" : [
  {
     "elevation" : 402.0888977050781,
     "location" : {
        "lat" : 11,
        "lng" : 11
     },
     "resolution" : 152.7032318115234
  }],"status" : "OK"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`results` in the posted JSON contains an array. so you might want to log e.g. the first results elevation like so: `alert(data.results[0].elevation);`

Answer (score 1):

Results is an array hence your issue.

Change this line:

```
data.results.elevation
```

With:

```
 data.results[0].elevation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
        $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: url,
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                   alert(data.results[0].elevation);
                }
            });
    }
```